# Dynamic .htaccess for CMS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, content-management-system

I am building a custom content management system for clients. It's similar to Joomla, but is alot easier to develop customized modules, components, etc. Obviously, they can change the name and alias of a webpage (article), and create menu items that are components and modules. I want to allow simple URLS using the alias. The problem I'm facing is updating the .htaccess when a user updates the alias.

I have dabbled very much in using .htaccess. I am just wondering if there's a way for a .htaccess file to dynamically rewrite URLS.

Comment: how most do it in a propper design like MVC, is pass the entire url string past the third `/` e.g: `^(.*)$` to the routing mechanism or drop it completely and just parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` global on initialization

Comment: Indeed, I've never understood the "mod_rewrite solves every problem" mindset that appears to pervade the PHP world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using .htaccess I ended up using $_SESSION variables and MySQL to handle a login session. Much easier.

Comment: I ended up using .htaccess to run every page through the index.php and then used mysql and php and process the parameters and return the proper information.